# Why does my Rust StackDFS implementation produce incorrect results?

Tags: algorithm, graph, rust

I am reading Luridas's book about algorithms and now I am at the Chapter 2 trying to implement StackDFS function. The purpose of this function is to "visit" every element of the graph.

Algorithm from the book:

```
StackDFS(G, node)→visited
//Input: G = (V,E), a graph
//node, the starting vertex in G
//Output: visited, an array of size |V | such that visited[i] is true if we
//have visited node i, false otherwise
  1 S ←CreateStack()
  2 visited ←CreateArray(|V |)
  3 for i ←0 to |V | do
  4 visited[i] ← false
  5 Push(S, node)
  6 while not IsStackEmpty(S) do
  7 c ←Pop(s)
  8 visited[c] ← true
     9 foreach v in AdjacencyList(G, c) do
       10 if not visited[v] then
           11 Push(S, v)
   12 return visited
```

My code:

```rust
use petgraph::graph::NodeIndex;
use petgraph::Undirected;

fn main() {
    let mut new = petgraph::Graph::<i32, (i32, i32), Undirected>::new_undirected();
    new.extend_with_edges(&[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 4)]);
    let index = 2;
    let mut visited = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..new.node_count() {
        visited.push(false);
    }
    StackDFS(&mut new, &index, &mut visited);
}

fn StackDFS<T>(G: &petgraph::Graph<T, (T, T), Undirected>, node: &usize, visited: &mut Vec<bool>) {
    let mut s: Vec<usize> = Vec::with_capacity(G.node_count());
    // for i in 0..G.node_count(){
    //   visited.push(false);
    //}
    s.push(*node);
    while s.is_empty() == false {
        let c = s.pop().unwrap();
        visited[c] = true;
        for el in G.neighbors(NodeIndex::new(*node)) {
            if visited[el.index()] == false {
                s.push(el.index());
            }
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", visited);
}
```

The output I get:

```
[false, true, true, false, true]
```

The output I expect:

```
[true, true, true, true, true]
```

I used a `Vec` instead of a stack, but I don't think this is the problem because `Vec` can provide the same functionality as a stack.

Comment: Small example, so debugging should not be too hard even with pen and paper.

Comment: After adding some missing `use` statements, this does **not** output `[false, true, true, false, true]`, instead it panics: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6032601fc2aca1e2b4db3bcfa604e927)

Comment: @sk_pleasant-EliasHolzmann I guess its my bad, I've formatted the code but `}` was missing, looks like i've misplaced, now code outputs as expected in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
for el in G.neighbors(NodeIndex::new(*node)) {
```

You are always accessing the neighbors of the same starting node. You are supposed to get the neighbors of the currently processed node.

Improved version:

```rust
use petgraph::{graph::NodeIndex, Undirected}; // 0.6.0

fn main() {
    let mut new = petgraph::Graph::<i32, (i32, i32), Undirected>::new_undirected();
    new.extend_with_edges(&[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 4)]);

    let index = 2;
    let mut visited = vec![false; new.node_count()];
    stack_dfs(&new, index, &mut visited);
}

fn stack_dfs<T>(
    g: &petgraph::Graph<T, (T, T), Undirected>,
    start_node: usize,
    visited: &mut Vec<bool>,
) {
    let mut s = Vec::with_capacity(g.node_count());
    s.push(start_node);

    while let Some(node) = s.pop() {
        visited[node] = true;
        for el in g.neighbors(NodeIndex::new(node)) {
            let idx = el.index();
            if !visited[idx] {
                s.push(idx);
            }
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", visited);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks you so much! I am so careles :D, it is a shame (but I'll improve that, of course)!